# Excel dynamic conditional formatting based on cell version 2

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

A few months back I posted the following question [Conditional formatting rows based on cell dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673311/conditional-formatting-rows-based-on-cell-dynamic/26674318#26674318).

At the time the formula provided was fantastic and still is however I'm redeveloping the spreadsheet and need something similar but I just can't figure out a solution.

I currently have a list of times in column A in increments of 1 hour from 9am to 9pm. In column B I would type 2 next to 9am it would somehow highlight 9am and 10am, now under that say you type 7 next to 11am it would highlight 11am, 12pm 1pm 2pm 3pm 4pm 5pm.

Hope that makes sense

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would seem to require the *Use a formula to which cells to format* option when creating a new CF rule.

[image]

Select A2:B14 with A2 as the *Active Cell* and choose Home ► Styles ► Conditional Formatting ► New Rule. Select the *Use a formula to which cells to format* option and supplt the following for *Format values where this formula is true:*

`=AND($A2>=INDEX($A$2:$A$14,MATCH(1E+99,$B$2:$B2)),$A2<(TIME(VLOOKUP(1E+99,$B$2:$B2,1),0,0)+INDEX($A$2:$A$14,MATCH(1E+99,$B$2:$B2))))`

Click <kbd>Format</kbd> and select some formatting. I chose an orange `Fill`. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to save the formatting choice(s) and then <kbd>OK</kbd> again to create the new rule. You should be left with something similar to the above sample image.